# Hide media library picker field title (display name) in Orchard 1.7

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I've create a new content type and added a Media Library Picker field to it.

When the content is displayed, the "Display Name" of the media library field is also displayed.

How do I hide it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by editing the media library module view.

Edit

Thanks to @Bertrand Le Roy,
The correct way is to override the module's view in the theme's folder using Alternates and NOT change the original view in the module's folder.

Comment: And by that you mean you've copied the view into your theme, then edited it?

Comment: No, I've edited the view inside the media library module folder. Is it possible to copy the view from the module into the theme folder and the override the default view?

Comment: It is not just possible, it's the only supported way of doing it. You should never, ever edit the files in a module you don't own. And you should never have to.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy what's the supported way to not display the content field display name?

Comment: Copy the file into your theme's views folder. That's called overriding the template.